# How to get records dynamically based on multiple filter criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the below table:

[image]

Can you please help me how to get results for the below scenarios dynamically?

If I supply Emp = 1 and HeaderID = 123 and Status = Failed, it should return the results as follows:

[image: EmpID HeaderID Status XML_Payload1 123 Failed <xml>1 321 Pending <xml>1 555 Pending <xml>2.]

If I supply Emp =1 and HeaderID = 111 and status = Failed, it should return the results as follows:

[image]

Thanks in advance, please.

Comment: This is a simple query with a WHERE clause that has several components. So which bit is troubling you? Is it the "dynamically" bit? If so, what client are you using to run the query?

Comment: And the problem is??

Comment: Hi, Below is my Query and it gives me the results of all the pending messages.

SELECT  A.EmpID, 
  A.HeaderID, 
  A.XML_Payload, 
  A.Status
FROM EmployeeRejection A, EmployeeRejection B
WHERE A.STATUS = 'PENDING' AND B.STATUS = 'FAILED'
AND A.EmpID = B.EmpID
ORDER BY A.HeaderID

Comment: and whats your problem here?

Comment: Hi,
In the above table, EmpId = 1 has status Failed, pending, pending, failed and pending with different header Ids. If I pass the where condition EmpId = 1, HEaderID = 123 and Status = Failed, all it should return the pending records after the failed record. The expected result should only be two rows that are header ID = 321 and 555. But my query giving the result all the pending records irrespective of first failed record.

Comment: Hi MSamuel83. I think there should exist at least one more column used as a criteria for ordering for those displayed data, such as time, or an extra id .. etc.

Comment: Hi  @BarbarosÖzhan

Can you point me the extra column to be added and values, please?

Comment: suppose you have another column such as time in the order of your displayed data in the question, don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need one more column, such as time or extra id or amount, for ordering as you displayed the data. To provide this criteria I added a time column( `time` ) to your data as in the below demonstration :

```
with t(empid,headerid,status,time) as
(
 select 1,123,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 17:00:00' from dual union all
 select 1,321,'Pending', '2019-06-22 17:10:00' from dual union all
 select 1,555,'Pending', '2019-06-22 17:20:00' from dual union all
 select 1,111,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 17:30:00' from dual union all
 select 1,222,'Pending', '2019-06-22 17:40:00' from dual union all
 select 2,333,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 17:50:00' from dual union all
 select 2,444,'Pending', '2019-06-22 18:00:00' from dual union all
 select 3,555,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 18:10:00' from dual 
), t2 as  
(
select sum(case when status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) 
       over (partition by empid order by time) as rn,
       t.*
  from t
) 
select *
  from t2
 where (rn, empid) in 
          ( select rn, empid 
              from t2 
             where empid = &i_empid -- 1 
               and headerid = &i_headerid -- 123
               and status = 'Failed' )
 order by time;
```

you can substitute `1` & `123` or `1` & `111` or `2` & `333` or `3` & `555` respectively, as you wish.

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/KKZB73863)</kbd>

**Edit**(*due to your comment*) :

If you want to return the first row with `Pending` status just after the one with `Failed` status you can try to use :

```
with t(empid,headerid,status,time) as
(
 select 1,123,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 17:00:00' from dual union all
 select 1,321,'Pending', '2019-06-22 17:10:00' from dual union all
 select 1,555,'Pending', '2019-06-22 17:20:00' from dual union all
 select 1,111,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 17:30:00' from dual union all
 select 1,222,'Pending', '2019-06-22 17:40:00' from dual union all
 select 2,333,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 17:50:00' from dual union all
 select 2,444,'Pending', '2019-06-22 18:00:00' from dual union all
 select 3,555,'Failed' , '2019-06-22 18:10:00' from dual 
), t2 as  
(
select sum(case when status = 'Failed' then 1 else 0 end) 
       over (partition by empid order by time) as rn,     
       t.*
  from t
), t3 as
(
select t2.*,
       row_number() over (partition by empid,rn,status order by time) as rn2      
  from t2
)
select *
  from t3
 where (rn,rn2, empid) in 
          ( select rn,rn2, empid 
              from t3 
             where empid = 1--&i_empid
               and headerid = 123 -- &i_headerid
               and status = 'Failed'
                )
   and status = 'Pending';
```

again you can substitute the same values used in the above query.

Comment: Hi Barbaros, 

Thank you so much for the query. I tried the query and it is working fine. Also, Can you please shed some light on how to get only pending records for the failed ones? I am trying to achieve but unfortunately I am not able to do.

Comment: you're welcome @MSamuel83 I did nothing special, seems there exist two cases, and no matter if the other cases exist for the status column the logic works because of being the member of `else` case. I think I didn't understand your question. Btw, please use text data rather than pictures in your future questions. People prefer text data for the questions, mostly.

Comment: Hi Barbaros,

Thank you once again!

If I supply Emp = 1 and HeaderID = 123 and Status = Failed, it should return only Pending results as follows:

EmpID        HeaderId       Status            XML_Payload
1                    321               Pending        <xml>

Can you please help me?

Comment: Thank you so much for the query Barbaros. It did really worked very well.